# ajax dropdown(country, state, city)

Tags: php, ajax

I need some ajax code to do some functions with drop down.

I have three table of values one for country, then state and city.

And i have three dropdown to show these values

first it should show

select country

select state

select city

in that drop downs(slect) respectively.

when i select united states from the first dropdown

in the second drop down it must show the states of the united states.

and again when i select  a state from the state dropdown

it must show the cities of that state in the third dropdown(city)

I want to do this with ajax.

can any one have a code to do this.

please help me.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Source Country Region Selector in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529129/open-source-country-region-selector-in-js)

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681854/select-dropdown-by-ajax/11682044#11682044

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) create 3 tables in db

```
country table
==============
countryId || countryName

stateTable
=============
stateId || stateName || countryName

city table
=============
cityId || cityName || stateId
```

2) now create 3 webservices
which sends data in json format

3) now on html page
create three select box and bind onchange event on each select box (except for city select), that event will send countryId for getStates Webservcie and stateId for getCities webservice. and bind received json states in state select box and cities in city select box

Comment: hey this i know, but i dont know the ajax function methods for this

Comment: do some googling for xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in so many ways...

1. Add an change event on the first dropdown menu;

Then, how do you plan to retrieve the states for related to the first menu, and the cityes related to the second one?

Are they in a database? Or in a js array (json?)?

If they are in the database, go with ajax requests.. else, use the array.

There are so many plugins and howto's for this tread, google a bit

**edit**: who did remove the `plz-send-me-teh-code` tag?!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old project so I did it through Javascript and not jQuery; I hope this is okay.

```
<td>Type</td>
<td>
      <select  id="type" onChange="propertyType(this.value)" name="type">
                            <option value="">All</option>
                            <option value="homes">Homes</option>
                            <option value="plots">Plots</option>
                            <option value="commercial">Commercial</option>
      </select>
</td>
```

this is js of propertyType

```
function propertyType(str){
  if(str=='' || str=='plots'){
    document.getElementById("type_h").innerHTML=""; 
    document.getElementById("bed").innerHTML="";    
    }   
    else if(str=='commercial'){
    document.getElementById("bed").innerHTML="";    
          }
 else{
  document.getElementById("type_h").innerHTML="<img src='<?php echo $serverimageurl?>ajax-loader-small.gif' />";
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("type_h").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax/propertytype.php?s="+str,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
   }
 }
```

This is propertytype.php

```
<?php
  $s=$_GET["s"];
  if($s=="homes"){
   ?>


 <select onchange="ajax_bed(this.value)" name="subtype" id="subtype" >
  <option value="">Type Of Houses</option>
  <option value="houses">Houses</option>
  <option value="flats">Flats</option>
  <option value="farmhouses">Farm Houses</option>
</select>

<?php
}
 if($s=="plots")
{
?>


 <?php
  }
  if($s=="commercial")
  {
  ?>
  <select name="subtype" id="subtype" >
   <option value="offices">Offices</option>
   <option value="shops">Shops</option>
   <option value="warehouses">Warehouses</option>
   <option value="factories">Factories</option>
   <option value="building">Buildings</option>
   <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
   <?php
  }
?>
```

This is ajax function for selecting the number of bed rooms

```
function ajax_bed(str){
  document.getElementById("bed").innerHTML="<img src='<?php echo $serverimageurl?>ajax-loader-small.gif' />";
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
  else
    {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("bed").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax/bedroomsselection.php?t="+str,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

This is bedroomsselection.php

```
<?php
$t=$_GET["t"];
if($t=="houses"||$t=="flats"||$t=="farmhouses")
{
?>
 <select id="bed" name="bed">
   <option>None</option>
   <option>Single Bed</option>
   <option>Double Bed</option>
   <option>three Bed</option>
   <option>Four Bed</option>
   <option>Five Bed</option>
   <option>Six Bed</option>
   <option>Seven Bed</option>
   <option>Eight Bed</option>
   <option>Ten Bed</option>
   <option>More Than Ten Bed</option>
</select>


 <?php
 }
?>
```

I hope you have got the idea now its time to code it yourself
Cheers