# in php how to load states onchange

Tags: php

in mysql database I have a country table with id and country_name rows and state table with id, country_id and state_name rows . in php I want state drop down to load on country  drop down selection.if anyone give me an example with two countries and two states it would be great.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?  We're all happy to help you debug your code, but shouldn't YOU write something first?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically populate options on dropdown lists based on selection in another dropdown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912302/how-to-dynamically-populate-options-on-dropdown-lists-based-on-selection-in-anot)

Comment: what you want is not clear? you have country list and your going to change the country. on country change you want to load the state is it?

Answer (score 0):

For this you need a cliend side language like JS and server side language like PHP. You have to send request from client to server to send which country is selected. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341171/ajax-dropdowncountry-state-city) and [this](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/01/populate-triple-drop-down-list-change-options-value-from-database-using-ajax-and-php.html)