# Select dropdown by ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need some ajax code to do some functions with drop down.  I have three table of values: one for country, then state and city. And I have three dropdown to show these values.

First it should show:

- select country
- select state
- select city

in that drop down(select) respectively.

When I select united kingdom from the first dropdown, in the second drop down it must show the states of the united kingdom. And again when I select a state from the state dropdown it must show the cities of that state in the third dropdown(city).

I want to do this with ajax. Does any one have a code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are already familiar with jQuery, you might want to check how to send ajax requests through $.ajax() (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) You can add the code for updating the list of states and cities in the success option and trigger the sending of ajax calls by binding an onchange event to the state and country dropdown. You can use .bind() (http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to do this.

Comment: Kindly check the links I attached first and you will see what I mean :)

Answer (score 0):

Snippet http://coffeestain-it.blogspot.fr/2011/08/mvc3-cascading-lists-using-ajax-and.html?m=1

Comment: sir thanks your answer.actually i am not used framework.i want normal codding.plz help me

Answer (score 0):

i have done what u need
[Go Here](http://www.teknords.com/aizaz/propertyadvisor/)

Select Type ,Location . i did it if u need the same i will post my code you can modify it

**Updated**
i am gona copy the code from the above site i made you modify it .i will paste code of "Type" Dropdown u can than do it for others too.
one thing more its very old project so i did it through Javascript and not jQuery hope it will irritate you. :(

```
<td>Type</td>
<td>
      <select  id="type" onChange="propertyType(this.value)" name="type">
                            <option value="">All</option>
                            <option value="homes">Homes</option>
                            <option value="plots">Plots</option>
                            <option value="commercial">Commercial</option>
      </select>
</td>
```

this is js of propertyType

```
function propertyType(str){
  if(str=='' || str=='plots'){
    document.getElementById("type_h").innerHTML=""; 
    document.getElementById("bed").innerHTML="";    
    }   
    else if(str=='commercial'){
    document.getElementById("bed").innerHTML="";    
          }
 else{
  document.getElementById("type_h").innerHTML="<img src='<?php echo $serverimageurl?>ajax-loader-small.gif' />";
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("type_h").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax/propertytype.php?s="+str,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
   }
 }
```

This is propertytype.php

```
<?php
  $s=$_GET["s"];
  if($s=="homes"){
   ?>


 <select onchange="ajax_bed(this.value)" name="subtype" id="subtype" >
  <option value="">Type Of Houses</option>
  <option value="houses">Houses</option>
  <option value="flats">Flats</option>
  <option value="farmhouses">Farm Houses</option>
</select>

<?php
}
 if($s=="plots")
{
?>


 <?php
  }
  if($s=="commercial")
  {
  ?>
  <select name="subtype" id="subtype" >
   <option value="offices">Offices</option>
   <option value="shops">Shops</option>
   <option value="warehouses">Warehouses</option>
   <option value="factories">Factories</option>
   <option value="building">Buildings</option>
   <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
   <?php
  }
?>
```

This is ajax function for selecting the number of bed rooms

```
function ajax_bed(str){
  document.getElementById("bed").innerHTML="<img src='<?php echo $serverimageurl?>ajax-loader-small.gif' />";
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
  else
    {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("bed").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax/bedroomsselection.php?t="+str,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

This is bedroomsselection.php

```
<?php
$t=$_GET["t"];
if($t=="houses"||$t=="flats"||$t=="farmhouses")
{
?>
 <select id="bed" name="bed">
   <option>None</option>
   <option>Single Bed</option>
   <option>Double Bed</option>
   <option>three Bed</option>
   <option>Four Bed</option>
   <option>Five Bed</option>
   <option>Six Bed</option>
   <option>Seven Bed</option>
   <option>Eight Bed</option>
   <option>Ten Bed</option>
   <option>More Than Ten Bed</option>
</select>


 <?php
 }
?>
```

I hope you have got the idea now its time to code it yourself
Cheers

Comment: @arafathossain i have updated my answer you can now see the code :)